# How to access knockout viewmodel from javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to understand how to manage the scope in my Javascript code.  Once I create a viewmodel, how do I access it from the rest of my javascript? (last line in this code generates a 'not defined' error

NOTE: I have found several posts on the differences between function/var for ko, but none have said there is a scoping advantage with using a var... so I have tried both methods.

```
//function AppViewModel() {
//    this.gridSize = ko.observable("30");
//    this.canvasWidth = ko.observable("600");
//    this.canvasHeight = ko.observable("600");
//    this.displayCoords = "Axial";
//    this.pixel="0";
//    this.hex="0";
//}
//ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

var AppViewModel = {
    gridSize: ko.observable("30"),
    canvasWidth: ko.observable("600"),
    canvasHeight: ko.observable("600"),
    displayCoords: "Axial",
    pixel:"0",
    hex:"0"
};
ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel );

var test = AppViewModel.gridSize;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the line "var test = AppViewModel.gridSize" does not work, when stepping through says is undefined.

Comment: It [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/G2HCq/).  We're going to need more information if there's still a problem.

Comment: Your problem is that you don't understand JavaScript, not that you don't understand Knockout.  No biggie, but you need to understand how to reference what you are trying to before you do.  Notice the differences between your commented code vs your view model...

Comment: yea the knockout is well documented and small, I am just stuck on Javascript.  Obviously this is so simple that people think I am asking something harder.

Comment: OK, have found that I can reference everything that is no ko.observable! (so var test = AppViewModel.hex works, but var test = AppViewModel.gridSize does not.

Answer (score 1):

ko.observable is a function and thus to reference a observable value you have to have brakets

e.g. from example above

```
var test = AppViewModel.gridSize();
```

found this good explanation
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html